# When did user change Display Name?

Tags: support, display-names

Is it possible to know when a user changed his display name?

Comment: No.  Name changes are limited to once every 30 days, to minimize the confusion.

Comment: Except for users who happen to have accounts a multiple sites on the SE network, i.e., just about everyone, who can change their display names whenever they want.

Comment: Next time don't miss a chance to ask for their phone number.

Answer (score 13):

That information is not available to regular users.

You *might* be able to find out by checking old comments. You'd have to see if there were any replies to the user with their old name. Make a note of the date. Keep looking until you find the youngest comment. That would be approximately when they changed their name.

I don't see any benefit in publicising it.