# How to obtain the user name history of a user

Tags: support, display-names

Stack Overflow allows users to change their user name. Is it possible to see the history of names that a user has?

Comment: IIRC, only moderators and team members have access to this information. I don't recall if mods can see the full history, or just the last couple records...

Comment: @Kendra Never had to look (thankfully) - but as far as I know, we've got access to that history. Think it's logged though, and yes, only mods have access to that.

Comment: [Some are tracked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518) (part of *The Many Memes of Meta*).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible if they were active on the site. The comments addressed to a user can be obtained using the Stack Exchange API, and old usernames can be (not always perfectly) recovered from those. See [Find old display names of a user](https://stackapps.com/q/6276).

Comment: This is not completely accurate but it's the best that is available.

Comment: The link in the post on Stack Apps no longer works. I have made a copy of that script: http://msleziak.com/stackexchange/oldusernames/
See also this post on MathOverflow Meta: [Recognizing identifiable users changing user names](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4426#4427)

Answer (score 9):

Not unless you're a moderator, no. If you have a question about your own history, feel free to raise a custom flag on one of your posts, and we can answer your question. But the details of any other user's history are private.

Also, you might want to refer to this related question: [When did user change Display Name?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271267/when-did-user-change-display-name)

Comment: OK. Reason for question: One *very* high rep user renamed himself and I wanted to confirm it's really him.

Comment: Is he still author of the same Qs and As? Yes? He's likely the same guy :D

Comment: @boot4life well, as Patrice said, just look at one of his posts and check. Also, there are only so many "very high rep" users.

Comment: @edCottrell thinking more on this though, I feel like somewhere someone mentioned you can see recent names a user had on his profile.... am I mixing my sites?

Comment: I don't remember any of his posts. Why do you think I would? Seems unlikely.

Comment: @Patrice for some reason I thought so, too.

Comment: @boot4life because he's a very high rep and you had him "in your sights"? Normally I know at least a couple of amazingly good answers from super high rep guys in the same tags as I

Comment: I don't associate a single post with any user. Not sure why anyone would. So many top users and so many epic posts.

Comment: @Patrice you can always piece it together from comments and cached pages (Internet Archive and so on), but otherwise, no.

Comment: @boot4life A few users, like me, include old user names in their profile's "About Me". Not common, but worth checking.